# R 4.2.1 crashes with tikzDevice

Tags: r, plot, latex, rstudio, tikzdevice

I am trying to use the following simple code in [r](/questions/tagged/r) `4.2.1` using [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) `2022.07.1 Build 554` but it crashes due to [tikzdevice](/questions/tagged/tikzdevice) (tried in both [r](/questions/tagged/r) `GUI` & [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) and both crash):

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz('simpleEx.tex', width = 3.5, height = 3.5)
plot(1, main = 'Hello World!')
dev.off()
```

[image]

I am getting the same error after re-installation of [tikzdevice](/questions/tagged/tikzdevice).

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] tikzDevice_0.12.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1 tools_4.2.1    filehash_2.4-3 grid_4.2.1
```

Comment: You seem to also be using RStudio. What version of RStudio are you using? Does that same issue happen if you run the code in the base R GUI?

Comment: Yes, I am using RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554. Getting the same error with R GUI.

Comment: You seem to be using a development version (0.12.3.1 is on CRAN). Have you tried reverting to the CRAN version ... ? (Although both versions work for me on Linux)

Comment: Yes, I tried tried with the stable version from CRAN. However getting the same error.

Comment: I don't get the error when using R 4.2.1, tikzDevice 0.12.3.1, Rstudio 2022.07.0 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installation of [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [tikzdevice](/questions/tagged/tikzdevice) solved the issue.

Comment: For similar problems using the free https://rstudio.cloud is a good option as you can choose and test different versions of R : 3.4.4 to 4.2.1

Comment: @Wael : Do they have an app for my cellphone?

Comment: Hi @IRTFM, it is an Rstudio IDE that you can run directly  from your browser (any modern browser).